# using data stored in factor with r

Tags: r

I have a data set where the "View(data$var[94])" command shows the "4" seen below but I can't seem use it because of the levels.  I'm wondering if there's a way for me to just grab the 4 in the example below.  I need the 4 to fill in another column.

```
> vcg_728_3_1$Value.tmp[98]
[1] 4
20651 Levels:  ...
```

Comment: To really go to the root of the problem you may want to change the way you import the data (e.g. specifying `colClasses` in `read.table`)

Comment: Can you expand on "grab the 4 in the example"? Perhaps it would be best if you would tell us what you're after. There is a chance that you're over complicating something simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it into a numeric vector:

```
f <- factor(1:10)
f
# [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
as.numeric(f)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```